# Is the following description means that $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n \ne 0$

Tags: calculus

Is saying that :

There is $N > 0$ such that for each $n>N$ we get $b_n\ne0$

Actually means that : $$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n \ne 0$$

Comment: Take $b_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$: $b_{n}\neq0$ for all $n$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_{n}=0$.

Comment: Did you notice that wuthin seconds three people came up with what is (I bet) the first example of a convergent sequence that you have ever encountered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $b_n = \dfrac1n$.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't.
For example, you could have $b_n=\frac1n$.